# Does setting "desired size: 0" prevent cluster-autoscaler from scaling up a managed node group?

Tags: amazon-eks, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I have an aws managed node group that is acting unexpectedly when I set both desired size  and minimum size to 0. I would expect that the managed node group would not have any nodes to start with, but that once I attempt to schedule a pod using a nodeSelector with the label `eks.amazonaws.com/nodegroup: my-node-group-name`, the cluster-autoscaler would set the desired size for the managed node group to 1, and a node would be booted.

However, the cluster-autoscaler logs indicate that the pending pod does not trigger a scale up because it wouldn't be schedulable: `pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)`. When I go set desired size to 1 in the managed node group manually however, the pod is scheduled successfully, so I know the nodeSelector works fine.

I thought this might be a labelling issue, as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#scaling-a-node-group-to-0): , but I have the labels on my managed node groups set to be auto-discoverable.

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --cloud-provider=aws
        - --namespace=kube-system
        - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/my-cluster-name
        - --balance-similar-node-groups=true
        - --expander=least-waste
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
        - --skip-nodes-with-system-pods=false
        - --stderrthreshold=info
        - --v=4
```

I have set the same labels on the autoscaling group:

```
Key                                             Value                             Tag new instances
eks:cluster-name                                 my-cluster-name                   Yes
eks:nodegroup-name                               my-node-group-name                Yes
k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled                true                              Yes
k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/my-cluster-name        owned                             Yes
kubernetes.io/cluster/my-cluster-name             owned                            Yes
```

Am I missing something? Or is this expected behavior for setting desired size to 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ugh, it turns out this is just an aws incompatibility with the cluster-autoscaler that they don't tell you about. You can scale your managed node group down to zero, but without a workaround, you can't scale it back up.

For the cluster-autoscaler to scale up a node group from 0, it constructs a pseudo node based on the nodegroup specifications, in this case the aws autoscaling group. For the cluster-autoscaler to know what labels to put on that pseudo node to check if it would allow a pod to be scheduled, you need to [add a specific tag to the nodegroup](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#how-can-i-scale-a-node-group-to-0).

Sadly, aws does not add this tag to the autoscaling group for you, and also does not propagate tags from the managed node group to the autoscaling group. The only way to make this work is to go add the tag to the autoscaling group yourself after it was created by the managed node group. The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/724).

Answer (score 1):

EKS now supports this with Cluster Autoscaler. https://realz.medium.com/reduce-amazon-eks-cost-by-scaling-node-groups-to-zero-41dce9db50ef

Comment: scaling to zero was never a problem, they just didn't think scaling back up from zero was an important function of that feature.